# How does my HTML page have access to socket.io on client-side?

Tags: html, node.js, linux, socket.io

I'm doing the socket.io chat tutorial and so far everything works. But I don't understand how the client-side is using socket.io code:

```
<!-- Load socket.io client-side -->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function (){

        var socket = io();

        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });

    });
```

So it's accessing it from "/socket.io/socket.io.js" but I don't have that anywhere in my folder. I don't get how the HTML webpage is accessing the socket.io.js file. Not sure how else to ask this. Where is this .js file?

Comment: Are you following the tutorial on https://socket.io/get-started/chat/? There is a line that states: "During development, socket.io serves the client automatically for us, as we’ll see, so for now we only have to install one module". So it seems that the socket.io installs a handler for the path `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. I have no experience with socket.io, but I guess that it is your responsibility to serve the script in a production environment.

Comment: Yeah I did read that part but I'm still confused about the handler and how or where the .js file is being reached. And yes that is the tutorial.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, serving the client script is handled in line 101 of `socket.io/lib/index.js`: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L101.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In above script file socket.io.js will be available in directory node_modules/socket.io-client

So if you want to do something like,

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
```

Then copy file from node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js
and paste it in your server directory.

Coming to your next question how to connect to server in client side,Here is your edited code to connect to server in client side.

```
$(function (){

    var socket = io("http://yourserver.com");

    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });

});
```

In above code http://yourserver.com is the address where your node server is running,If you are doing offline on localserver then it can be something like this,

```
var socket = io("http://192.168.0.103:3000");
```

In above code 3000 is a port on which server is running,And 192.168.0.103 will replace with your local ip address.
Hope this will help.!

Comment: Above answer is for connecting client to server if your client side files are being served by different server,say your index.html is on apache server and your node server is running at different address.If your files are being served by node server only than you don't have to specify address of server and it will be like var socket=io();

Comment: I was focused on the first part of your answer, I understand how the connection works. I'm just curious how the client is finding the socket.io javascript file: <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>  You say it looks for it in node_modules but I don't understand, the word "node_modules" isn't even anywhere in that src attribute in the script tag. How does it know to look for it there?

Comment: Actually I'm also confused how it gets that file but some how i figured out and found that file and after copying that file it worked for me

Comment: Oh so you just copied it from node_modules into the same directory as the .html file and it worked? No problems?

Comment: Yeah its working just chage the src attribute from .html file